# A good answer deleted!

Tags: discussion

What to do if a good answer to my question, which also had some associated discussion in the form of comments, is missing (deleted)? To clarify, there was nothing objectionable or irrelevant in it.

In the event no other answer was found suitable, this one could have even been the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 4):

I have 10k rep so I can see deleted answers and their comments. This [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50936/9001) had 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes and was "deleted by owner Dec 10 at 8:21".

No reason was given. Perhaps the owner, Theta30, thought the other answers covered it better.

Comment: Thanks so much! Four upvotes and volunteer to delete one's own answer? Anyway, I guess there's little that can be done now? I am concerned about the discussion under the answer and as I said, could have even "accepted" the answer.

Comment: Theta30 can undelete their answer, and may do so if you ask somehow, especially if it will be accepted. Alternatively, I think moderators can vote to undelete under some circumstances. If you just want the comments, I could probably paste them in here.

Comment: I may not be able to commit accepting the answer, as it depends on the situation when it is restored or before expiry of the bounty. However, I think there was an interesting discussion in the comments as I said. Thanks again, @Hugo.

Comment: OK, I've sent a message to @Theta30 in chat linking back here, let's see if there's a response.

Comment: Yes I deleted for all. That is normal as a result of critical thinking; in fact there is even a badge (Disciplined) for deleting a question with at least 3 votes.

Comment: @Theta30 Getting a badge is not the reason for deleting a post, though.

Comment: @Hugo You can see comments of deleted posts, when the comments are not deleted. Only moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: @Jasper Loy I have deleted one post in that day and in general I do not delete many. Didn't you ever delete one of your own posts?

Comment: I did not delete the post to get the badge.

Comment: @Theta30: It's fine with me anyway. I understand you may have your reasons for withdrawing an answer. It's just that the answer had contributed to a good discussion. It had added an important dimension, which is most valuable to any debate. Thank you all the same and please do continue to participate actively, esp., on english.SE

Comment: @Hugo: Thank you for all the help! Being pretty new around here, it was very reassuring to have someone guide me around.